# i have a formula in cell b1 that searches in cells a101:a200, how do i get it to autofill for cell c1 to search in cells a201:a300?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using XLOOKUP formula on sheet 2 cell A 1.
The lookup value is sheet 1 cell N 2, the lookup array is in cells M 101 through M 200, the return array is in cells C 101 through C 200.
How do I auto fill the Cell B 1 for the lookup arrays and return arrays to show M/C 201 through M/C 300, Cell C 1 to match M/C 301 through M/C 400, ect... all the way to Cell L 1?

Comment: This is really hard to see what you are trying to accomplish. Can you share some of the spreadsheet so we can see what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your existing formula in A1, replace M101:M200 with this:

```
OFFSET(Sheet1!$M$1,100*COLUMN(),0,100,1)
```

Then copy across to B1 etc. This starts at cell M1 and "walks" down 100 rows x the column in which this formula is found, so 100 for A1, 200 for B1 etc. Then returns 100 rows in a single column.